# Why only heads up when a push notification is received multiple times?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I am developing a flutter application that uses firebase_messaging and `flutter_local_notifications`. By referring to various YouTube and blogs, it was implemented to work well in the background situation. However, in Android's foreground situation, it behaves strangely.

[image: When I first received the notification]

When I first received the notification, the message didn't heads up and was just displayed in the app bar.

[image: second time I receive the same notification]
However, from the second time I receive the same notification, the message heads up as I want.

I want to implement a message heads up from the first reception even in the foreground situation.

This is my code:

main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => appState,
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => SafetyConversationProvider(),
      ),
    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();

  static _MyAppState of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyAppState>()!;
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late AppStateNotifier _appStateNotifier;
  late GoRouter router;

  NotificationServices notificationServices = NotificationServices();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    router = createRouter(_appStateNotifier);
    notificationServices.requestNotificationPermission();
    notificationServices.firebaseInit(context, router);
    notificationServices.setupInteractMessage(context, router);
    notificationServices.isTokenRefresh();
    notificationServices.getDeviceToken().then((value) async {
      print('Device Token = ');
      print(value);

      registerAppTokenResult = await RegisterAppTokenCall.call(
        token: value,
      );
      if (registerAppTokenResult?.succeeded ?? true) {
        if (!(getJsonField(
              (registerAppTokenResult?.jsonBody ?? ''),
              r'''$.count''',
            ) ==
            0)) {
          print("register complete");
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      .
      .
      .
```

notification_service.dart

```
class NotificationServices {
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  void requestNotificationPermission() async {
    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
        alert: true,
        announcement: true,
        badge: true,
        carPlay: true,
        criticalAlert: true,
        provisional: true,
        sound: true);

    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      print('User granted permission');
    } else if (settings.authorizationStatus ==
        AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
      print('User granted provisional permission');
    } else {
      AppSettings.openNotificationSettings();
      print('User declined or has not accepted permission');
    }
  }

  void initLocalNotifications(
      BuildContext context, RemoteMessage message, GoRouter router) async {
    var androidInitializationSettings =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_notification_icon');
    var iosInitializationSettings = const DarwinInitializationSettings();

    var initializationSetting = InitializationSettings(
      android: androidInitializationSettings,
      iOS: iosInitializationSettings,
    );

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSetting,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (payload) {
      handleMessage(context, message, router);
    });
  }

  void firebaseInit(BuildContext context, GoRouter router) {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification!.android;

      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("notifications title:" + notification!.title.toString());
        print("notifications body:" + notification.body.toString());
        print('count:' + android!.count.toString());

        print("notifications channel id:" +
            message.notification!.android!.channelId.toString());
        print("notifications click action:" +
            message.notification!.android!.clickAction.toString());
        print("notifications color:" +
            message.notification!.android!.color.toString());
        print("notifications count:" +
            message.notification!.android!.count.toString());
      }

      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        initLocalNotifications(context, message, router);
        showNotification(message);
      } else {
        showNotification(message);
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> showNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      "important_channel",
      "important_channel_name",
      description: "important_channel_description",
      importance: Importance.max,
      showBadge: true,
    );

    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      channel.id.toString(),
      channel.name.toString(),
      channelDescription: channel.description.toString(),
      icon: '@drawable/ic_notification_icon',
      importance: channel.importance,
      priority: Priority.max,
      //ticker: 'ticker',
    );

    const DarwinNotificationDetails darwinNotificationDetails =
        DarwinNotificationDetails(
      presentAlert: true,
      presentBadge: true,
      presentSound: true,
    );

    NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidNotificationDetails, iOS: darwinNotificationDetails);

    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0,
        message.notification!.title.toString(),
        message.notification!.body.toString(),
        notificationDetails,
      );
    });
  }

  Future<String> getDeviceToken() async {
    String? token = await messaging.getToken();
    return token!;
  }

  void isTokenRefresh() async {
    messaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((event) {
      event.toString();
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('refresh');
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> setupInteractMessage(
      BuildContext context, GoRouter router) async {
    RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

    if (initialMessage != null) {
      handleMessage(context, initialMessage, router);
    }

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((event) {
      handleMessage(context, event, router);
    });
  }

  void handleMessage(
      BuildContext context, RemoteMessage message, GoRouter router) {
    if (message.data['appPage'] != null &&
        message.data['queryParams'] != null) {
      router.pushReplacementNamed(message.data['appPage'],
          queryParams: json.decode(message.data['queryParams']));
    }
  }
}
```